# Whats a dynamic way implementing a ScrollViewer in Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollviewer, itemscontrol

I am having trouble getting a `ScrollViewer` to work properly if it's not the only element in the window. I want to scroll through a list of items(a list set as `ItemsSource`) but also want other elements to be visible in my window. Now i don't know how to set the `height` relative to the other elements. Is that even a valid approach or am i doing it completly wrong?

```
<Window x:Class="FactorioWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FactorioWpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" 
    Closing="Window_Closing">

<StackPanel>

    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Items">
            <MenuItem Header="Add" Click="ItemsAdd_Click" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0">
            <ItemsControl Name="ItemViewerItemsControl">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

I searched for nearly three hours but the only solutions i could find, were to set the scroll viewer as the top element.

Comment: first, you are using a grid with no RowDefinition. Is that intended?
Did you try StackPanel? RowDefinition? DockPanel? ListView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not gonna work with StackPanel. StackPanel grows based on content. Actually it will work with stack panel but you need to define height of ScrollViewer. Use grid with row definitions.

```
   <Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
            mc:Ignorable="d" Height="350" Width="525"  >
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Menu Grid.Row="0">
                <MenuItem Header="Items">
                    <MenuItem Header="Add" Click="MenuItem_OnClick" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>

            <Grid Grid.Row="1">

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Column="0">
                    <ItemsControl  Name="ItemViewerItemsControl">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Comment: Works greak, thank you so much. Never thougt about not using a StackPanel.